# Postgres 10.6: UPDATE on partially indexed column sometimes hangs

Tags: postgresql, update, locking, postgresql-10

I have a table (6 small columns 2M+ rows) with a column `dead`. There are two indexes on this table, both are partial with `dead = false`.

From time to time I want to scan the table and mark rows with `dead = true`, for that I have a worker that runs an `UPDATE` command.

**The update set is pretty large - 600K+ rows and usually completes in a reasonable time - 10-20 seconds. But sometimes, this `UPDATE` seems to last forever.**

When I execute a table lock before the update it doesn't get stuck (so far), but the optimal solution would be without doing a full table lock every time the workers executes.

I tried getting `pg_locks` and `pg_stat_activity` while the query runs forever (contains the UPDATE command):

```
loyaltytest=> SELECT * FROM pg_locks;
  locktype  | database | relation | page | tuple | virtualxid | transactionid | classid | objid | objsubid | virtualtransaction |  pid  |           mode           | granted | fastpath 
------------+----------+----------+------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------+-------+--------------------------+---------+----------
 relation   |    16403 |    11577 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 6/1612             | 16305 | AccessShareLock          | t       | t
 virtualxid |          |          |      |       | 6/1612     |               |         |       |          | 6/1612             | 16305 | ExclusiveLock            | t       | t
 relation   |    16403 |  4474123 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/2476             | 15772 | AccessShareLock          | t       | t
 relation   |    16403 |  4474123 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/2476             | 15772 | RowExclusiveLock         | t       | t
 relation   |    16403 |  4473792 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/2476             | 15772 | AccessShareLock          | t       | t
 relation   |    16403 |  4473792 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/2476             | 15772 | RowExclusiveLock         | t       | t
 relation   |    16403 |  4472987 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/2476             | 15772 | AccessShareLock          | t       | t
 relation   |    16403 |  4472987 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/2476             | 15772 | RowExclusiveLock         | t       | t
 relation   |    16403 |  4472977 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/2476             | 15772 | AccessShareLock          | t       | t
 relation   |    16403 |  4472977 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 5/2476             | 15772 | RowExclusiveLock         | t       | t
 virtualxid |          |          |      |       | 5/2476     |               |         |       |          | 5/2476             | 15772 | ExclusiveLock            | t       | t
 relation   |    16403 |  4474123 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 7/1533             | 20435 | RowExclusiveLock         | t       | t
 relation   |    16403 |  4473792 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 7/1533             | 20435 | RowExclusiveLock         | t       | t
 relation   |    16403 |  4472987 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 7/1533             | 20435 | RowExclusiveLock         | t       | t
 virtualxid |          |          |      |       | 7/1533     |               |         |       |          | 7/1533             | 20435 | ExclusiveLock            | t       | t
 relation   |    16403 |  4472977 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 7/1533             | 20435 | ShareUpdateExclusiveLock | t       | f
(16 rows)

loyaltytest=> SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
 datid |   datname   |  pid  | usesysid |  usename  |            application_name            |  client_addr  | client_hostname | client_port |         backend_start         |          xact_start           |          query_start          |         state_change          | wait_event_type | wait_event | state  | backend_xid | backend_xmin |                                                      query                                                      |  backend_type  
-------+-------------+-------+----------+-----------+----------------------------------------+---------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------+------------+--------+-------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------
 16403 | loyaltytest | 15772 |    16394 | avnadmin  |                                        | 84.160.85.240 |                 |       56788 | 2019-02-12 13:28:22.170926+00 | 2019-02-12 14:39:08.321904+00 | 2019-02-12 14:39:08.321904+00 | 2019-02-12 14:39:08.321917+00 |                 |            | active |             |    124343810 | WITH entries AS                                                                                                +| client backend
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                 (                                                                                              +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                         SELECT                                                                                 +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                                 additions.id AS id,                                                            +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                                 additions.amount - coalesce(SUM(subtractions.amount),0) AS balance,            +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                                 additions.expirydate <= now() AS passed_expiration                             +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                         FROM                                                                                   +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                                 loyalty_ledger AS additions                                                    +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                         LEFT JOIN                                                                              +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                                 loyalty_ledger AS subtractions                                                 +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                         ON                                                                                     +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                                 subtractions.dead = FALSE AND                                                  +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                                 additions.id = subtractions.referenceentryid                                   +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                         WHERE                                                                                  +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                                 additions.dead = FALSE AND additions.referenceentryid IS NULL                  +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                         GROUP BY                                                                               +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                                 subtractions.referenceentryid, additions.id                                    +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                 ), dead_rows AS (                                                                              +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                         SELECT                                                                                 +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                                 l.id AS id,                                                                    +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                                 -- only additions that still have usable points can expire                     +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                                 l.referenceentryid IS NULL AND e.balance > 0 AND e.passed_expiration AS expired+| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                         FROM                                                                                   +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                                 loyalty_ledger AS l                                                            +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                         INNER JOIN                                                                             +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                                 entries AS e                                                                   +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                         ON                                                                                     +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                                 (l.id = e.id OR l.referenceentryid = e.id)                                     +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                         WHERE                                                                                  +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                                 l.dead = FALSE AND                                                             +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                                 (e.balance <= 0 OR e.passed_expiration)                                        +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |            ORDER BY e.balance DESC                                                                             +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                 )                                                                                              +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                 UPDATE                                                                                         +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                         loyalty_ledger AS l                                                                    +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                 SET                                                                                            +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                         (dead, expired) = (TRUE, d.expired)                                                    +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                 FROM                                                                                           +| 
       |             |       |          |           |                                        |               |                 |             |                               |                               |                               |                               |                 |            |        |             |              |                         dead_row                                                                                | 
 16403 | loyaltytest | 16305 |    16394 | avnadmin  | psql                                   | 84.160.85.240 |                 |       56838 | 2019-02-12 13:35:58.823704+00 | 2019-02-12 14:39:49.194077+00 | 2019-02-12 14:39:49.194077+00 | 2019-02-12 14:39:49.194082+00 |                 |            | active |             |    124343815 | SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;                                                                                 | client backend
 16403 | loyaltytest | 17038 |    16394 | avnadmin  |                                        | 34.76.174.87  |                 |       35418 | 2019-02-12 13:47:08.356476+00 |                               | 2019-02-12 14:39:48.726918+00 | 2019-02-12 14:39:48.727001+00 | Client          | ClientRead | idle   |             |              |                                                                                                                 | client backend
 16403 | loyaltytest |  5089 |    16394 | avnadmin  |                                        | 34.76.174.87  |                 |       56354 | 2019-02-12 10:47:07.877739+00 |                               | 2019-02-12 14:39:48.330438+00 | 2019-02-12 14:39:48.33051+00  | Client          | ClientRead | idle   |             |              | COMMIT                                                                                                          | client backend
 16403 | loyaltytest |  5088 |    16394 | avnadmin  |                                        | 34.76.174.87  |                 |       53548 | 2019-02-12 10:47:07.849865+00 |                               | 2019-02-12 14:39:48.332492+00 | 2019-02-12 14:39:48.33256+00  | Client          | ClientRead | idle   |             |              | COMMIT                                                                                                          | client backend
 16403 | loyaltytest |  5081 |    16394 | avnadmin  |                                        | 35.187.83.177 |                 |       46390 | 2019-02-12 10:47:03.103153+00 |                               | 2019-02-12 14:39:48.093619+00 | 2019-02-12 14:39:48.093744+00 | Client          | ClientRead | idle   |             |              |                                                                                                                 | client backend
 16403 | loyaltytest |  5153 |    16394 | avnadmin  |                                        | 35.187.83.177 |                 |       47142 | 2019-02-12 10:48:07.11505+00  |                               | 2019-02-12 14:39:47.719775+00 | 2019-02-12 14:39:47.719867+00 | Client          | ClientRead | idle   |             |              |                                                                                                                 | client backend
 16403 | loyaltytest |  5158 |    16394 | avnadmin  |                                        | 34.76.174.87  |                 |       54014 | 2019-02-12 10:48:08.498088+00 |                               | 2019-02-12 14:39:47.850591+00 | 2019-02-12 14:39:47.850675+00 | Client          | ClientRead | idle   |             |              |                                                                                                                 | client backend
(17 rows - insufficient privileges omitted )
```

I was thinking it could be related to the indexing on the updated column, but then why should locking the table would solve it?

Comment: I think it is probably just luck that you haven't seen the "hang" when taking an explicit table lock.  It is more likely that the query plan changes based on changing statistics about the table.  Can you capture an "EXPLAIN" of the query (obviously not "EXPLAIN ANALYZE", as that wouldn't finish) during a hang and compare it to normal?  Perhaps set up a job to record an EXPLAIN once a minute, and than use timestamps to retrieve the plans that happen contemporaneously with a hang, and with a non-hang.

Comment: I can do that and post an update. Good idea!
I've also noticed that if I `ANALYZE loyalty_ledger` before I run the update, it won't hang. I'm thinking it's related to the indexed column `dead` changing so often in my tests.